# my manifest.json file contains an error that I can't find

Tags: json, syntax

I'm writing a very simple Chrome extension and when I try to load it as an unpacked extension, I get the following error:

Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 16, column: 2, Syntax error.

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Backchannel",
"description": "",
"version": "1.0",
"icons": {
"128": "128.png"
},
"app": {
"urls": [
"http://backchannel.glitch.me/"

],
"launch": {
"web_url”: “http://backchannel.glitch.me/"
}
},

"permissions": [
"unlimitedStorage",
"notifications"
]
}
```

Comment: Those fancy quotes `”“` shouldn't be there.

Comment: that fixed it! thanks I don't know why I missed it. :P